# Why does resize the amp-iframe not take effect after the AMP page loads?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, amp-html

demo

```html
<amp-iframe id="sample-resizable-iframe"
            title="Resizable iframe example from 200x200 to 300x300 "
            width="150"
            height="150"
            sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin"
            resizable
            frameborder="0"
            src="https://test.com/AMP/reasize-iframe.html">
  <amp-img layout="fill" src="https://test.leadscloud.com/amp-site/placeholder.png" placeholder></amp-img>
  <div overflow tabindex="0" role="button" aria-label="Show more">Click to show more</div>
</amp-iframe>
```

reasize-iframe.html

```js
var message = {
  sentinel: 'amp',
  type: 'embed-size',
  height: size,
  width: size,
  right: 10
};
console.log('post new embed-height', message);
window.parent.postMessage(message, '*');
```

it work on simple demo, but not work on complex pages after the AMP page loads.
I tried to delay execution by setTimeout 3500ms, sometimes work, sometimes not work.
Does anybody know how to solve it?

Comment: Do you see any error logs amp page or in iFrame page in console? Also why you using window.parent.parent? What are two domains in use for AMP and Iframe?

Comment: no error. It is valid to invoke resize method by click the button after the page loads.Oh! I write it wrongly. no two domains.

Answer (score 1):

If I had to guess, it would be because the iframe is in view when you attempt the resize.

Source from
https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/42c3b1de1ad3474ed47b047208fb1bb3f570dbcc/extensions/amp-iframe/1.0/component.js

[image: amp source]

Comment: That is right, it will resize if we put it out of the viewport. Also it depends on a situation, sometimes when I refresh the page it will resize. I thought there is a problem in my code.